# How to filter subform using listbox

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

Good day,

I have one form call **Check Router**. In that subform I have one **text box (TxtPartNo)**, one **list box (LstPartNo)** and one **subform (CheckRouteSubform)**.

These are the roles of those function

1. TxtPartNo --> User will key in the Item Description that they wanted to check its         Route.After that,they will click add button.
2. LstPartNo --> its row source type is ***value list***. After the user click Add Button, the Item Description that they key in will insert in this list box. Then they will **select all data list** and **click on check button**.
3. CheckRouteSubform --> This subform is based on CheckRouteQuery. After check button is click, I wanted it to be filter based on that Item Description. If it **contain** but not exactly **equal** that part_No, it will show in this subform.

   ```
         example : user key in = FCLF-8531
                   subform will show data that contain FCLF-8531-RX, FLCF-8531-AX.
   ```

here I attached the picture of the form [image: CheckRouter]

Below are the picture of query :

[image]

As you can see i create criteria of Item Description based on the listbox.

and in check button I used this code:

```
  Private Sub CmdCheckRoute_Click()
  Dim i As Integer


  For i = 0 To Forms!CheckRoute!LstPartNo.ListCount - 1
  Forms!CheckRoute!LstPartNo.Selected(i) = True
  Next i

 DoCmd.RunSQL "CheckRouteQuery"

 End Sub
```

However, it does not want to show what I need. :( Help me please.

Comment: Not entirely clear to my why listbox is involved. If you want form filtered by single item input to textbox and it needs to be wildcard parameter, use `LIKE [txtPartNo] & "*"`.

Comment: @June7 I want it to be list box because the user will key in more than 1 item description.

Comment: Then how would you expect to employ LIKE and wildcard on multiple items? A solution might involve use of a 'temp' table - table is permanent but records are temporary - to build a dataset for desired output. Review this tutorial for conventional method of using listbox to filter a form or report http://allenbrowne.com/ser-50.html. Your question is really too broad.

Comment: up..............